# JSON to JQuery: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm fairly new to javascript and jquery development. I have a table of values I'm fetching in PHP and formatting as a JSON string, because JSON looks like a great way to get data into javascript. But I'm having trouble addressing the javascript variable.

The JSON data is in a very simple format. It looks like this:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"Bob","haircolor":"brown"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Carol","haircolor":"Red"}
]
```

And so on. None of the entries are complex. It's just flat rows of data.

I'm using $.getJSON() from JQuery to place the data in a variable like so:

```
var people;
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    people.push(data);
});
```

According to console.log(data), the object 'data' is getting populated with the contents of my JSON string. But the push is generating these errors in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

What am I missing? And is there any other information you need to help me on this? I've ground to a halt on this project because of this problem, and I'm just too much of a javascript newbie to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable people must be an array. Change the first line to

```
var people = [];
```

At the moment "people" is just undefined and the .push() method only works on arrays.

Comment: That definitely got rid of the error, but for some reason, people.length is coming back zero. Shouldn't each entry be addressable with each array at people[0], people[1], and so on? Or am I misunderstanding the way .push() works?

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP writes the output like this:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"Bob","haircolor":"brown"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Carol","haircolor":"Red"}
]
```

You need to assign that whole structure to `people`:

```
var people;
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    people = data;
});

// note that you can't access anything inside people here
// only when the json has been processed
```

Comment: I missed the obvious. +1 to you, and deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your variable as an array before you push to it:

```
var people = new Array();
```

Answer (score 1):

try initializing people variable as an array

```
var people = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
  $.each(data, function(i, people){
     console.log(people);
  });
});
```