# Accessing JSON data in a Javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

It's embarrassing to have to ask, but I freely admit I'm an unseasoned Javascript developer, and I just can't figure this out. Hopefully, this will be dead simple for someone else, and I want to thank everyone here ahead of time for the help this site continually provides me.

A couple days ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538104/json-to-jquery-what-am-i-doing-wrong), and am no longer getting that error. But I've run into a wall trying to actually access the data stored in the variable. My JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"Bob","haircolor":"Brown"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Carol","haircolor":"Red"}
]
```

It's going into a variable like this:

```
var people=[];
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    people.push(data);
});
```

Thanks to initializing people as an array, I no longer get any error messages. But I can't access the contents of people, either. `people.length` returns a 0, and `people[0]` and `people[1]` are undefined.

It's there, I know it's all there, but I'm having a devil of a time figuring out where.

Comment: Is your script returning `application/json` as the response MIME type?

Comment: Have you verified that `data` is correct?

Comment: Using Firebug or a similar tool, can you verify that the browser is actually receiving the desired JSON?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using `people` right after the ajax call would you?

Comment: `people=data;` tried it?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302702/jquery-return-value-using-ajax-result-on-success , also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery

Comment: @tadman It doesn't matter, jQuery will attempt to convert it since the method is specifically `$.getJSON`. Something important to check is with `$.getJSON("", function () {}).error(function () { alert("error"); });`

Comment: Also, if your Json is already a list of people objects why not just do `var people;` then `people=data` instead of nesting it in another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: http://jsfiddle.net/hUq7k/

```
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    $.each(data, function(i, people){
       console.log(people.id); //<------this should output "1, 2"
    });
});
```

make sure you are getting the `response data`.

Comment: This was it! And it's so simple, too. I'm embarrassed at having to ask it in the first place. Thank you so much!

Comment: It worked very well, and gave me some ideas on easier debugging, too. I only recently learned about console.log(), and it has a lot of really wonderful uses.

Answer (score 2):

`people` only gets values **after** the ajax event happens.

Call some callback function after you put the data into the `people` array.

Answer (score 0):

The following *should* work, if the server is actually returning the expected JSON:

```
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    var people = data;
    alert("people.length: " + people.length);
    if (people.length > 0) {
        alert("people[0].id: " + people[0].id);
    }
});
```

The following should *not* work, i.e., `people` will be `undefined`, because $.getJSON is an asynchronous method and this code is attempting to access `people` before the AJAX operation has completed.

```
var people;
$.getJSON("php/getpeople.php", function(data){ //getpeople.php generates the JSON
    people = data;
});

alert("people.length: " + people.length);
if (people.length > 0) {
    alert("people[0].id: " + people[0].id);
}
```